# Trouble understanding istringstream in C++

Tags: c++, string, istringstream

I am new to C++ and I was wondering how I can understand what functions and classes do. For example I was told to use "istringstream" for a homework assignment. I have looked online and found the site cplusplus.com with a lot of references. The problem I have is understanding the [reference page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/istringstream/).

On the "istringstream" reference page I am given the following code:

```
// istringstream constructors.
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <sstream>      // std::istringstream
#include <string>       // std::string

int main () {

  std::string stringvalues = "125 320 512 750 333";
  std::istringstream iss (stringvalues);

  for (int n=0; n<5; n++)
  {
    int val;
    iss >> val;
    std::cout << val*2 << '\n';
  }

  return 0;
}
```

In the code above, it does exactly what I need it to do for my assignment but I do not understand WHY it works. So they created a istringstream object called iss, then later used "iss >> val". That is the part I am confused with. What exactly does it do?

I have tried reading the text above where it explains what each function in the class does but I did not understand any of it. For example, one of the first lines on the reference page says

```
default (1)   explicit istringstream (ios_base::openmode which = ios_base::in);
```

How do I interpret this line? From what I can see it is a function that takes one argument but what is "ios_base::openmode which = ios_base::in".

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt -- If that leaves you confused, then you really need to cover some fundamentals and should read some introductory material on C++.

Comment: You might start with re-reading any materials you have been given or if that does not help, find a basic tutorial or book on C++ to supplement that material.

Comment: Do you understand what `std::cin >> val;` would do? If so, it would be fairly easy to explain `istringstream`. If not, you need to gain more fundamental C++ understanding.

Comment: If your homework is telling you to use iostreams before you're sure what a function is ... I guess you can just learn the magic incantation for now, and _how_ it works will be covered later. The documentation may be at the wrong level of abstraction for you right now. If your course _never_ explains how this works, it's a bad course and you should read a good book.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, do you guys have any good books on C++ for beginners that you recommend? If not I will try to look for some myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [this is the page you're looking for](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/). This defines that mysterious `>>` operator. It is overloaded several different ways, which means it's working like a `scanf` function for several different data types.

Your compiler looks at `iss >> val` and says "Hmm...`iss` is an `istringstream` and `val` is an `int`. Aha! Looks like `istringstream` has an `operator>>` that takes an `int&`, I'll use that!"

**Edit:** `istream` has an `operator>>` for `int&`. `istringstream` inherits those.

Answer (score 3):

Think in [`std::istringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/) as a stream interface adapter of `std::string`.

Is like writing that `std::string` in the console or file and read with `std::cin` or `std::ifstream`, it provide the interface (`get()`, `peek()`, etc...) for read the underlying storage (in this case `std::string`). The rest of the `operator>>` overloads probably use the basic reading functions to read the custom types (`int`, `double`, etc...).

The line: `default (1)   explicit istringstream (ios_base::openmode which = ios_base::in);` is declaring a constructor that receive a default parameter name `which` with default value `ios_base::in` (this indicate that you could read from the stream)

Answer (score 1):

*later used "iss >> val". That is the part I am confused with. What exactly does it do?*

The expression `iss >> val` is "syntactic sugar" for the function call 
`iss.operator>>(val)` where the formal parameter is defined as a reference to an int value. The function itself takes the address of `val` and writes a new value at this location. This is supposed to be "symbolized" by the `>>` symbol in your original expression `iss >> val`.